# Select entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

There are 3 tables

**News**

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
| news_id |     title     |     short     |     body     | photo_id  | etc... |
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
|  881971 | Article Title | Article short | Article Body |    658998 |        |
|  881972 | Article Title | Article short | Article Body |    658999 |        |
+---------+---------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

**Term**

```
+-----+--------------+
| tid | news_term_id |
+-----+--------------+
|  14 |       881971 |
|   2 |       881972 |
|   2 |       881973 |
+-----+--------------+
```

**Photo**

```
+--------+----------------------------------------+
|   id   |                  path                  |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 658998 | /files/2015/2/14304641562238139741.JPG |
| 658999 | /files/2015/2/14304641562238139742.JPG |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

I need select all articles in table **News** where **tid** in **Term** equal 2 (for example) and include photo path from **Photo** table

**My query:**

```
select n.*, t.*
from news n
inner join term t 
    on n.news_id = t.news_term_id 
    and t.tid = 2
```

Comment: How do we relate tables `photo` and `news`? We could need a column like `news_id` in table `photo`.

Comment: In News table have photo_id column and in Photo column have id column equal photo_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current query is fine, you just need to bring in the `photo` table. Just add one more join:

```
select n.*, p.path
from term t
inner join news n on n.news_id = t.news_term_id
inner join photo p on p.phto_id = n.photo_id
where t.tid = 2
```

Note: I started the query from the `term` table, since I find that it makes the logic clearer (filtering condition `t.tid = 2` goes to the `where` clause).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add in my existing request. But your solution better! You help me out for the second time, thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome @CodePuch! I did not relate to your previous question but now I see.